# Все запросы возвращают 404 not found

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-web-api

Пытаюсь настроить asp.net mvc + angularjs приложение. Столкнулся с проблемой, то не могу настроить web api логику. Любые запросы на бэкенд возвращают 404 not found.

Пример метода клиентской части:

```
$scope.test = function () {
    $http.post('/api/Test', "some string")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Success");
        }, function () {
            console.log("Failure");
        });
}
```

Бэкенд:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Test")]
    public void Test(string str) {
        var a = str;
    }
```

Также добавлял RoutePrefix на уровне контроллера, но это ситуацию не исправило.
Буду признателен, если подскажете где я допустил ошибку.

```
namespace xmlReader.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Test")]
        public string Test(string str) {
            return str;
        }
    }




namespace webappang
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}


    namespace webappang {
    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в браузере назимаете F12, идете во вкладку Network и смотрите, какие именнор запросы вы отправляете.

Comment: http://localhost:49909/api/Test

Comment: покажите настройки вашего API

Comment: Сам ниего не настраивал. Где расположены эти настройки, в Global.asax.cs?

Comment: тип проекта какой? Фреймвор какой у вас?

Comment: .net Framework 4.7.1

Comment: проект asp.net webApplication

Comment: web или web api ?

Comment: ещё у вас метод `public void Test(string str)` ничего не возвращает, какой ответ от него вы ожидаете?

Comment: проект web api. Метод будет возвращать строку, поправил на нужную сигнатуру, но вызов метода в любом слуае не происходит

Comment: Покажите контроллер +  `RouteConfig` +  `WebApiConfig`

Comment: namespace xmlReader.Controllers {
 public class HomeController : Controller {
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("api/Test")]
  public string Test(string str) {
   return str;
  }
 }

Comment: namespace webappang
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

Comment: namespace webappang {
 public class RouteConfig {
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
  }
 }
}

Comment: в вопрос, добавьте в вопрос это, я же глаза сломаю это читать в комментах :)

Comment: Вы добавили в ответ, а я просил в вопрос. Вы можете править свой вопрос, добавляя туда нужные данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема номер раз, вы хотите иметь API, но используете для этого обычный контроллер. Если вы хотите писать API, но  наследуйтесь от `ApiController`

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Test")]
    public string Index([FromBody] string str)
    {
        var a = str;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Проблема два - вы хотите принимать чисто строку как параметр. Вы можете это сделать, но это немного сложнее, чем принимать Json. Во первых вам понадобится аттрибут `[FromBody]`, по вторых вам придется начинать переданную строку [со знака `=`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842548/312041), например `=TestMessage`.

Результат

[image: ...]